# Uploading pictures on iPhone to Facebook application doesn't work

Tags: iphone, graphics, facebook

Trying to upload picture from my iPhone to Facebook.  In Facebook app, when I choose a picture and select 'Upload' I should see progress bar as picture uploads.  Instead when I press 'Upload' the upload screen disappears and picture is not uploaded.

I tried closing the app and restarting it again, it still doesn't work. I reinstalled the application and then it will let me upload couple of pictures until it will start failing again.

I have iPhone 4 running OS 4.2.1

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings->general->Location Services, switch facebook to "ON" and try again.
Hope this helps!

Comment: although i'm not sure why, this fixes it.